# Redirect not logged in users to login page on unauthorized access to folder ManagerPages

Tags: c#, asp.net-membership, asp.net-webpages

This is what I get by default:

HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

```
Requested URL htt p://localhost:56335/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fManagerPages%2fVideoManager.aspx
Physical Path      c:\users\pc\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Lab8\Lab8\Account\Login
Logon Method       Anonymous
Logon User     Anonymous
Request Tracing Directory      C:\Users\Pc\Documents\IISExpress\TraceLogFiles\LAB8
```

I tried with:

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="Error.aspx" mode="On">
      <error statusCode="401" redirect="Account/Login.aspx" />
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="Forbidden.aspx" />
    </customErrors>
```

but, no success, like I didn't change anything.
I also tried with almost every solution I found on stackoverflow, google, but no matter what I do this page always appears. The code doesn't even get in codebehind, so how can I redirect them? In membership perhaps?

```
Edit:
```

I replaced Account/Login with Login.aspx in browser address tab and it worked fine. How to replace this in code?

Comment: have you tried setting `mode="Off"` also since you have a path in your redirect for example `Account/Login.aspx` try changing that to `"~/Account/Login.aspx"`

Comment: @DJKRAZE tried now, nothing changed.

Comment: Why don't you remove these lines `<error statusCode="401" redirect="Account/Login.aspx" />
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="Forbidden.aspx" />` and in code call the Redirect code..

Comment: I've tried that too, it doesn't even reach the code.

Comment: I have tried it in my code and it works perfectly.. however I am not using error status code.. how ever you could check code based on the following to determine how to redirect to pages `HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri` then create a method to check if it contains a specific string what ever your condition is..

Comment: It doesn't even go in codebehind, therefore I can't do anything from there.

Comment: sounds like you are doing something incorrectly.. when and where are you expecting to invoke the EventHandler that calls the code.. make sure that you have properly registered the events it's kind of hard to determine what you are doing without seeing any real relevant code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experimented a bit with `<rewrite>` tag and got it to work when I changed the url to match the wrong path "`Account/Login`":

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules> 
         <rule name="Unauthorized access" stopProcessing="true">
           <match url="Account/Login" />
           <action type="Redirect" url="/Login.aspx"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

Now it's not only redirecting to "`Login.aspx`" but it also has the original query string: `Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fManagerPages%2fVideoManager.aspx`

Answer (score 0):

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="DForm" loginUrl="/login.aspx" />
    </authentication>
.....
<location path="ManagerPages">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```